Nhibernate cache and how the querying works
Let us assume I have table product with column Id,Name ,price.

Using Nhibernate if I get Product with Id 1  as below and update price
var product = session.Get<Product>(1);

 product.price = 150;

 Session.Merge(product);

 var products = session.CreateCriteria<Product>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Lt("Price", 100))
        .List<Product>();

Now in the same session if I run above query after merge I am getting the result as below:

It is giving Apple also in the list but the price is showing 150 which I updated. I should not update this value until we commit the transaction. When I query it should exclude the product which I updated in the current session.
I have gone through the internet about cache of Nhibernate and what I understood is it searches the first-level cache and second-level cache when we use criteria.SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal) and SetCacheable(true). I tried this also while querying but I am getting same result.
I want to know how nhibernate querying in this case because if I think it is running query on DB but I am getting the price latest as 150 instead of 50. It is using the data from cache and running the condition on DB records?
I can't commit my product price before querying as we are using unit of work for particular functionality.
How to handle this type of situation or what is the correct approach?
Thanks,
Nagasree.
